# Ext JS 4 ItemSelector example

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I wanted to create an ItemSelector in ExtJS 4.1, but they don't seem to have a working "title" property for the two lists. Here is exactly what I want:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/multiselect/multiselect-demo.html

(observe the two titles: "available" and "selected")

and here is "the same example" applied for the 4.1 version:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/multiselect/multiselect-demo.html

That is why I have downloaded extJS 4.1 and added the ItemSelector and MultiSelect files from an earlier version(4.0.7). Then I have copied almost everything from the first example, but nothing is done and I gen no error message.

Please tell me how I should make such an ItemSelector work(preferably using ext JS 4.1, since it's the latest version and it seems wrong to start with a deprecated version, but at this point, any working solution will do, since I ran out of ideas).

Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Insert title here

```
<!-- ExtJS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- Shared -->
<!--     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../shared/example.css" /> -->

<!-- Example -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./resources/css/ItemSelector.css" />
```

and the app.js file:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});
//Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', './ux');
Ext.require([
    'Ext.form.Panel',
    'Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect',
    'Ext.ux.form.ItemSelector'
]);

 Ext.onReady(function(){
console.log("ready");

/*
 * Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect Example Code
 */
var msForm = Ext.widget('form', {
    title: 'MultiSelect Test',
    width: 400,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: 'multiselect',
    items:[{
        anchor: '100%',
        xtype: 'multiselect',
        msgTarget: 'side',
        fieldLabel: 'Multiselect',
        name: 'multiselect',

        allowBlank: false,
        // minSelections: 2,
        // maxSelections: 3,

        store: [[123,'One Hundred Twenty Three'],
                ['1', 'One'], ['2', 'Two'], ['3', 'Three'], ['4', 'Four'], ['5', 'Five'],
                ['6', 'Six'], ['7', 'Seven'], ['8', 'Eight'], ['9', 'Nine']],

        value: ['3', '4', '6'],

        ddReorder: true
    }],

    tbar:[{
        text: 'Options',
        menu: [{
            text: 'Set value (2,3)',
            handler: function(){
                msForm.getForm().findField('multiselect').setValue(['2', '3']);
            }
        },{
            text: 'Toggle enabled',
            handler: function(){
                var m = msForm.getForm().findField('multiselect');
                if (!m.disabled) {
                    m.disable();
                } else {
                    m.enable();
                }
            }
        },{
            text: 'Toggle delimiter',
            handler: function() {
                var m = msForm.getForm().findField('multiselect');
                if (m.delimiter) {
                    m.delimiter = null;
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Delimiter Changed', 'The delimiter is now set to <b>null</b>. Click Save to ' +
                                  'see that values are now submitted as separate parameters.');
                } else {
                    m.delimiter = ',';
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Delimiter Changed', 'The delimiter is now set to <b>","</b>. Click Save to ' +
                                  'see that values are now submitted as a single parameter separated by the delimiter.');
                }
            }
        }]
    }],

    buttons: [{
        text: 'Clear',
        handler: function(){
            var field = msForm.getForm().findField('multiselect');
            if (!field.readOnly && !field.disabled) {
                field.clearValue();
            }
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Reset',
        handler: function() {
            msForm.getForm().reset();
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Save',
        handler: function(){
            if(msForm.getForm().isValid()){
                Ext.Msg.alert('Submitted Values', 'The following will be sent to the server: <br />'+
                    msForm.getForm().getValues(true));
            }
        }
    }]
});

console.log(msForm);


var ds = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    data: [[123,'One Hundred Twenty Three'],
        ['1', 'One'], ['2', 'Two'], ['3', 'Three'], ['4', 'Four'], ['5', 'Five'],
        ['6', 'Six'], ['7', 'Seven'], ['8', 'Eight'], ['9', 'Nine']],
    fields: ['value','text'],
    sortInfo: {
        field: 'value',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }
});

/*
 * Ext.ux.form.ItemSelector Example Code
 */
var isForm = Ext.widget('form', {
    title: 'ItemSelector Test',
    width: 700,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: 'itemselector',

    tbar:[{
        text: 'Options',
        menu: [{
            text: 'Set value (2,3)',
            handler: function(){
                isForm.getForm().findField('itemselector').setValue(['2', '3']);
            }
        },{
            text: 'Toggle enabled',
            handler: function(){
                var m = isForm.getForm().findField('itemselector');
                if (!m.disabled) {
                    m.disable();
                } else {
                    m.enable();
                }
            }
        },{
            text: 'Toggle delimiter',
            handler: function() {
                var m = isForm.getForm().findField('itemselector');
                if (m.delimiter) {
                    m.delimiter = null;
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Delimiter Changed', 'The delimiter is now set to <b>null</b>. Click Save to ' +
                                  'see that values are now submitted as separate parameters.');
                } else {
                    m.delimiter = ',';
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Delimiter Changed', 'The delimiter is now set to <b>","</b>. Click Save to ' +
                                  'see that values are now submitted as a single parameter separated by the delimiter.');
                }
            }
        }]
    }],

    items:[{
        xtype: 'itemselector',
        name: 'itemselector',
        anchor: '100%',
        fieldLabel: 'ItemSelector',
        imagePath: '../ux/images/',

        store: ds,
        displayField: 'text',
        valueField: 'value',
        value: ['3', '4', '6'],

        allowBlank: false,
        // minSelections: 2,
        // maxSelections: 3,
        msgTarget: 'side'
    }],

    buttons: [{
        text: 'Clear',
        handler: function(){
            var field = isForm.getForm().findField('itemselector');
            if (!field.readOnly && !field.disabled) {
                field.clearValue();
            }
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Reset',
        handler: function() {
            isForm.getForm().reset();
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Save',
        handler: function(){
            if(isForm.getForm().isValid()){
                Ext.Msg.alert('Submitted Values', 'The following will be sent to the server: <br />'+
                    isForm.getForm().getValues(true));
            }
        }
    }]
});

});
```

and finally, this is my folder structure:

```
-app.js
-bootstrap.js
-ext-all-debug.js
-NewFile.html
-ux
   -form
         -ItemSelector.js
         -MultiSelector.js
         -layout
              -ItemSelector.js
              -MultiSelect.js
-resources
   -css
         -ext-all.css
         -ItemSelector.css
```

Comment: To fix this it would take some pretty nasty overrides on some already questionable code.  Is this for learning purposes or is a fix needed for production?

Comment: @pllee I need such a widget for production. This code is copied from the Sencha demos and tutorials. I thought it was correct. I am really new to Ext JS and all the coding I have done, was with the documentation in front of me. This is why I can't be sure about anything. Any tips would help.

Answer (score 3):

```
items:[{
    xtype: 'itemselector',
    name: 'itemselector',
    anchor: '100%',
    fieldLabel: 'ItemSelector',
    imagePath: '../ux/images/',

    store: ds,
    displayField: 'text',
    valueField: 'value',
    value: ['3', '4', '6'],

    allowBlank: false,
    // minSelections: 2,
    // maxSelections: 3,
    fromTitle : 'Available'
    toTitle : 'Selected'
    msgTarget: 'side'
}],
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example [MultiSelect & ItemSelector - 4.1](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/extjs-build/examples/multiselect/multiselect-demo.html).

Make sure that your version of `Ext.ux.form.ItemSelector` and `Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect` are the same as in `extjs 4.1` sources (you can find in `extjs-4.1.1/examples/ux/form` directory).

I had the same problem and update of `MultiSelect.js` and `ItemSelector.js` fixed my problems.

Answer (score 0):

To get it to work you can put in these overrides before your app code executes. (this needs to be run with 4.1 to have it run in 4.0 use Ext.override)

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.override.MultiSelect', {
    override : 'Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect',

    setupItems : function() {
        var me = this;
        me.boundList = Ext.create('Ext.view.BoundList', {
            deferInitialRefresh : false,
            multiSelect : true,
            store : me.store,
            displayField : me.displayField,
            disabled : me.disabled
        });
        me.boundList.getSelectionModel().on('selectionchange', me.onSelectChange, me);
        //START OVERRIDE
        this.selectedPanel = new Ext.panel.Panel({
            bodyStyle : 'border: 0;',
            layout : 'fit',
            title : me.title,
            tbar : me.tbar,
            items : me.boundList
        });

        return {
            xtype : 'container',
            layout : 'fit',
            items : this.selectedPanel
        };
    }
});

Ext.define('Ext.ux.form.override.ItemSelector', {
    override : 'Ext.ux.form.ItemSelector',

    fromTitle : 'Available',
    toTitle : 'Selected',

    setupItems : function() {
        var items = this.callParent();

        this.fromField.selectedPanel.setTitle(this.fromTitle);
        this.toField.selectedPanel.setTitle(this.toTitle);

        return items;
    }
})
```

I would advise against using this component in production.  As you already know it is not supported by Ext and it is prone to change.  Also the code is pretty bad and the two components can't be more tightly coupled.

Answer (score 0):

There are some versions of Extjs having bug with Itemselector. This is fairly easy to overcome. 
 
1. Go to your Itemselector.js file and find setupItems function.
 
2. This function uses createList() function to create FromField and ToField.
 
3. Function Overloading : Create another function just like createList() and pass it a parameter (this is the title you want to set), ( eg : createList(param) )
 
4. In createList(param) function, just add title: param 
5. Now in your setupItems function replace createList() with createList('Avaiable') and createList('Selected'). 
6. You are DONE.

Example Code :

```
createList: function(param){
    var me = this;
    return Ext.create('Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect', {
            submitValue: false,
            flex: 1,
            dragGroup: me.ddGroup,
            dropGroup: me.ddGroup,
            store: {
                model: me.store.model,
                    data: []
            },
            title: param,
            displayField: me.displayField,
            disabled: me.disabled,
            listeners: {
                boundList: {
                        scope: me,
                        itemdblclick: me.onItemDblClick,
                        drop: me.syncValue  
            }
            }
    });
},

setupItems: function() {
        var me = this;

        me.fromField = me.createList('Available');
        me.toField = me.createList('Selected');

        // add everything to the from field at the start
        me.fromField.store.add(me.store.getRange());

        return {
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [
                me.fromField,
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    margins: '0 4',
                    width: 22,
                    layout: {
                        type: 'vbox',
                        pack: 'center'
                    },
                    items: me.createButtons()
                },
                me.toField
            ]
        };
    },
```

Thanks.